# Summing over a calculated field of concatenated strings (split acct #s)

Tags: sql, db2, excel-2007, ibm-midrange

To start: I am querying a DB2 server built into the IBM i System package from Excel 2007 using "From Microsoft Query" and straight-up SQL.  It is a financial database.

The DB is structured such that account #s are split up into 8 integer fields for fund, division, department, activity 1, activity 2, element 1, element 2, and object.  In order to make query results readable I have concatenated them with the following code:

```
select 
  right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMFUND" as Char(8))))),3)||'-'
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(t1."GMDPT" as Char(8))))),2) 
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMDIV" as Char(8))))),2) ||'-'
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMSTAB" as Char(8))))),2)
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMSTAS" as Char(8))))),1)||'.'
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMELM1" as Char(8))))),1)
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMELM2" as Char(8))))),1)||'-'
||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMOBJ" as Char(8))))),2)
  as AJAccount
```

It's a bit difficult to read, so I'll explain: For each field I am concatenating '00' to each # typecast as an 8-char string (to add leading zeroes), then trimming the trailing blank spaces (from the typecast conversion), and finally grabbing the correct # of digits for each using right().  That ends up making up a single acct # which we use day-to-day in the following format:

000-0000-000.00-00

Now here comes the more complicated part.  I need to sum a calculated field for debits and credits, defined by the following:

```
IFNULL(T1."GMDAMT",0)-IFNULL(T1."GMCAMT",0) as Trans_Total
```

But that isn't summed yet.  And that's where I run into my problem.  When I query those two fields I get accurate results for each and every transaction in the DB, labeled w/ acct #s.  But when I attempt to enclose the [debits - credits] field in a SUM() aggregate function and group by 'AJAccount' my query throws an error.

The error points to the following section of my concatenated acct # field:

```
right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMOBJ" as Char(8))))),2)
```

Specifically it highlights "GMOBJ" as the source of the error.  But without the SUM() function, the code runs just fine, producing results that look like the following:

```
001-0000-243.00-00  |  166898.00
001-0000-244.00-00  | -166898.00    
161-0000-243.00-00  |    3000.00     
161-0000-244.00-00  |   -3000.00    
470-0000-243.00-00  |    4999.00     
470-0000-244.00-00  |   -4999.00    
490-0000-243.00-00  |    1000.00     
490-0000-244.00-00  |   -1000.00
```

This isn't even the half of what I really need to do (because the transaction data is split off into 4 different tables by transaction type that I will eventually need to JOIN on...but that's another task).  But until I get this working I am at a dead stop.

This is the whole block of code:

```
select 
    right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMFUND" as Char(8))))),3)||'-'
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(t1."GMDPT" as Char(8))))),2) 
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMDIV" as Char(8))))),2) ||'-'
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMSTAB" as Char(8))))),2)
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMSTAS" as Char(8))))),1)||'.'
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMELM1" as Char(8))))),1)
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMELM2" as Char(8))))),1)||'-'
  ||right(trim(trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMOBJ" as Char(8))))),2)
      as AJAccount,
  SUM(IFNULL(T1."GMDAMT",0)-IFNULL(T1."GMCAMT",0)) as Trans_Total
from "HTEDTA"."GM310AP" T1
where T1."GMAPYR" = 2014
group by 'AJAccount'
```

I thought maybe I typo'd or something, so I did the following easier query:

```
select 
T1."GMFUND",
SUM(IFNULL(T1."GMDAMT",0)-IFNULL(T1."GMCAMT",0)) as Trans_Total
from "HTEDTA"."GM310AP" T1
where T1."GMAPYR" = 2014 and T1."GMAPMO" between 1 and 4
group by T1."GMFUND"
order by T1."GMFUND"
```

and it ran just fine, producing the following results:

```
  1  |  20090901.49  
111  |     32635.15  
114  |         0.00  
115  |         0.00  
131  |      5916.66
```

So I suspect I am lacking knowledge about calculated fields and SUM().  Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have you decided on `CHAR` format instead of `INT(8)`?

Comment: Because the RIGHT() function requires a string input and an INT type wouldn't keep the leading zeroes anyway.  A colleague wrote that for his own use and allowed me to use it, I assumed he used the most efficient method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You're right about the leading zeroes.

Comment: On DB2 we would use `RIGHT(DIGITS(gpmfund),3)` as a much simpler way to maintain leading zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am assuming the error is SQL0206 - Column or global variable AJAccount not found.

If true, the problem is that the GROUP BY clause is looking for a column in the database table, not a derived column in the SELECT clause.  Try putting the entire derived column in your GROUP BY:

```
select...
where...
group by right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMFUND" as Char(8))))),3) || '-' || right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(t1."GMDPT" as Char(8))))),2) || right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMDIV" as Char(8))))),2) || '-' ||  right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMSTAB" as Char(8))))),2) || right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMSTAS" as Char(8))))),1) || '.' || right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMELM1" as Char(8))))),1) || 
right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMELM2" as Char(8))))),1) || '-' || right(trim (trailing from (concat('00',cast(T1."GMOBJ" as Char(8))))),2) 
order by 1
```

Comment: I thank everyone for their replies, they all helped to make the code shorter and easier to work with.  But only this solution actually solved the GROUP BY problem.  I think it's something to do with the latest version of MS Office Query not liking aliased names.  I originally used ' because that is what Google/MS indicated was the solution for those unable or unwilling to patch.

Comment: And, unfortunately, while this works in the independent SQL Script stand-alone I use for testing code before pasting into Excel's MS Query...it does not actually work in Excel.  It comes back at me with an "Incorrect column expression" error.

Comment: And just 5 minutes later (darn you 5 minute edit limit) I figured out that it was the "DIGITS()" function causing it.  Apparently the SQL version in MS Query doesn't have that, explaining why my colleague used the code he did in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A simplified example using a [common-table-expression](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcomtexp.htm):

```
WITH gm310ap AS (SELECT 
    RIGHT('00'||DIGITS(gmfund),3) || '-' ||
    RIGHT('0'||DIGITS(gmdpt),2) || 
    RIGHT('0'||DIGITS(gmdiv),2) || '-' || 
    RIGHT('0'||DIGITS(gmstab),2) ||
    RIGHT(DIGITS(gmstas),1) || '.' ||
    RIGHT(DIGITS(gmelm1),1) ||
    RIGHT(DIGITS(gmelm2),1) || '-' ||
    RIGHT('0'||DIGITS(gmobj),2) AS AJAccount,
    COALESCE(gmdamt,0) - COALESCE(gmcamt,0) AS Trans_Total
FROM "HTEDTA"."GM310AP"
WHERE gmapyr = 2014)
SELECT AJAccount, SUM(Trans_Total)
FROM gm310ap
GROUP BY AJAccount
```

Documentation for the scalar functions:

- [COALESCE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscacoales.htm)
- [DEC](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscadec.htm)
- [DIGITS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscadigits.htm)
- [RIGHT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscaright.htm)

Comment: RIGHT(DIGITS()) would be simpler & faster, eh?

Comment: @WarrenT You are correct.  I updated the answer to show the simplified method.  The zero fill is probably unnecessary too but we don't know how the original fields are defined.

Comment: If gmfund were only defined as 2 digits, then you could say `'0'||digits(gmfund)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have shown is exactly what you ran, then your query has a simple syntax issue.  You said `GROUP BY 'AJAccount'` which is a string literal.  Double quotes (`"AJAccount"`) would make it a case sensitive column reference.  However, when you said `as AJAaccount` you did not use double quotes, so the name is not case sensitive and so you do not need the quotes in the GROUP BY.

Assuming your columns are at least as long as the portions you are trying to extract, I would try the following query:

```
SELECT (  RIGHT(DIGITS(gmfund),3) ||'-' 
       || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmdpt),2)
       || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmdiv),2) || '-'
       || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmstab),2)
       || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmstas),1) || '.'
       || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmelm1),1)
       || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmelm2),1) || '-'
       || RIGHT('0'||DIGITS(gmobj),2)
       ) as AJAccount,
       sum(gmdamt) - sum(gmcamt) AS Trans_Total
    FROM "HTEDTA"."GM310AP"
    WHERE gmapyr = 2014
    GROUP BY AJAccount
```

My guess is that there may be plenty of other queries that would use this concatenated account number.  If this is the case, you might consider creating a view to store this logic  for use elsewhere, perhaps like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW HTEDTA.GM310AP_AC
  SELECT (  RIGHT(DIGITS(gmfund),3) ||'-' 
         || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmdpt),2)
         || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmdiv),2) || '-'
         || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmstab),2)
         || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmstas),1) || '.'
         || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmelm1),1)
         || RIGHT(DIGITS(gmelm2),1) || '-'
         || RIGHT('0'||DIGITS(gmobj),2)
         ) as AJAccount,
         gmdamt,
         gmcamt      -- include any other useful columns
    FROM HTEDTA.GM310AP
```

Once that has been created, you can write queries such as

```
SELECT AJAccount,
       SUM( IFNULL(gmdamt,0) - IFNULL(gmcamt) ) as Trans_Total
  FROM HTEDTA.GM310AP_AC
  GROUP BY AJAccount
  ORDER BY AJAccount
```

Or

```
WITH Q AS
( SELECT AJAccount,
         SUM(gmdamt) as TotD,
         SUM(gmcamt) as TotC
  FROM HTEDTA.GM310AP_AC
  GROUP BY AJAccount
)
SELECT AJAccount, 
       TotD - TotC   as Trans_Total
  FROM Q
  ORDER BY AJAccount
```

P.S.  You only need the IFNULL if those columns are nullable.  This is traditionally rather rare on DB2 for i, so if you check this, you might simplify things a bit more for yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I have restricted access to the database, read-only.  I would have liked to create a view for each of my 4 transaction tables, but I will have to do something with unions or joins it seems.  Also, thank you for fixing the tables in my original post.  How does one do that correctly?

Comment: To see edits made to a question, click the [Edited ...](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21191493/revisions) link above the editor's info.

Comment: Your DBA, or whoever in IT is responsible for the database, may be willing to create a view like that, as long as there would be enough use of it.